# SEO URL Rewrite not working

Tags: java, jsp, seo, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am working on some e-commerce project. Now I need to rewrite all URL for SEO. 
I tried converting

```
userOrganization/campaignPreviewBuyer.htm?id=8aa697ea3b9d9e03013b9dd998dd000b&city=Bangalore&page=big-villas
```

When user clicks on the above link I want

```
/userOrganization/campaignPreviewBuyer/8aa697ea3b9d9e03013b9dd998dd000b/Bangalore/big-villas
```

to be seen.

In my jsp I have put

```
<%= response.encodeURL("../userOrganization/campaignPreviewBuyer.htm?id=8aa697ea3b9d9e03013b9dd998dd000b&city=Bangalore&page=big-villas") %>">Testing</a>
```

And in urlrewrite.xml

```
<outbound-rule>
<from>/userOrganization/campaignPreviewBuyer.htm?id=([0-9a-zA-Z]+)&amp;city=([a-z]+)&amp;campaign=([a-z]+) </from>          
<to>/userOrganization/campaignPreviewBuyer/1$/2$/3$</to></outbound-rule>
```

But its not working. Please anyone help where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try $1 $2 and $3 instead of 1$ 2$ and 3$.

Comment: I am using tuckey's urlrewrite to rewrite all my urls and its working fine. But I dont want the rules to apply for .css,.js.jpg,.png files. I tried <rule>
 <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">\.[a-z]+$</condition> <from>/userOrganization/([a-z]+)/campaignPreviewBuyer.htm$</from>
    <to>/userOrganization/campaignPreviewBuyer.htm?id=8aa697ea3b9d9e03013b9dd998dd000b</to>
</rule> but its not working. Please anyone help

Comment: Haha, I used to work with Tuckey, but I'm not an expert on the urlrewrite tool that he wrote.  This seems like a brand new question to me and maybe you should ask it as a new question.  But seriously, I would expect your notequal condition `\.[a-z]+$` to match `.htm` as well as the suffixes that you want it to match; and that's why your rule seems not to be working.  Maybe you could write that condition differently, so that it only traps the suffixes you want it to.

Comment: Tried doing, <rule>
 <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">(.*(.jpg|.gif|.css|.js$|.png).*)$</condition>
    <from>/userOrganization/([a-z]+)/campaignPreviewBuyer.htm$</from>
    <to>/userOrganization/campaignPreviewBuyer.htm?id=8aa697ea3b9d9e03013b9dd998dd000b</to>
</rule> still not woking

Comment: Don't forget to escape the dots before each suffix.